# Win7 Python 2.6 using ctypes I can not call functions in a COM dll

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

On Win7 using Python 2.6 and ctypes I am trying to call functions in a COM dll with no success.
 
Here is a code snippet of what I am doing.

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
h_func = c_int(0);
h_c    = c_int(0);
h_text = ctypes.create_string_buffer(32);
usbDll = ctypes.WinDLL ("c:\\temp\\PwrUSBDll.dll");
CheckStatusPowerUSB = usbDll.CheckStatusPowerUSB;
InitPowerUSB = usbDll.InitPowerUSB;
#
#===This is where it all goes down the tubes.
#
InitPowerUSB (byref(h_func), byref(h_text), byref(h_c));
#
# I keep getting a WindowsError: exception: access violation writing 0x00000000
#
print h_func.value;
print h_text.value;
print h_c.value;
```

InitPowerUSB takes in two parameters to return data to and it returns a return code.
Can anyone help me with this. I have this working in C# with no problems.

Comment: You appear to be passing three parameters rather than two. Unless you show us either the C header file, or your C# pinvoke, we've no idea how this function should be called.

Comment: What's more, this isn't COM. That's just a plain DLL call.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [`pypowerusb`](https://github.com/superjoe30/pypowerusb/tree/master/lib)?

Looking at the [relevant header file](https://github.com/superjoe30/pypowerusb/blob/master/lib/PwrUSBInc.h), `InitPowerUSB` takes only *one* argument, a pointer to integer, while you supply three arguments.

Try calling the function with only a single argument.

Comment: Also it's `cdecl` rather than `stdcall` if that header is to be trusted

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4zxe9k8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx is should use `__stdcall`. But I'm not a windows guy, so I don't really know.

Comment: The header file you linked to doesn't specify calling convention. The default is __cdecl. The article you linked to in the comment is generic. Each DLL makes its own choices.

Comment: Shouldn't you get a exception from `ctypes` when using the wrong calling convention on windows? (if there is no access violation, that is)

Comment: Yes, you should. And I think the calling convention error can only be shown once the function returns. By the way, I did up-vote, because this is a good answer. I'm just trying to add some extra information to help.

Comment: I realized that my original explanation about the first argument was incorrect, because the poster uses `byref`, so I changed that part. What is not exactly clear to me is how the extra arguments and/or a wrong calling convention result in an access violation.

Comment: Could easily be calling convention mismatch.